# How do I add a label programmatically BUT to a specific view controller?

Tags: view, controller, uilabel

Hey guys I know this a very simple question, but I'm stuck.

So far i know to add a label you do:

```
UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 50, 200, 40)];
[myLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[myLabel setText:@"Hi Label"];
[[self view] addSubview:myLabel];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `self` with your view controller.

```
UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 50, 200, 40)];
[myLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[myLabel setText:@"Hi Label"];
[[viewController view] addSubview:myLabel];
```